# Jmeter: Syntax error while sending a http delete request

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, http-delete

We are sending a HTTP DELETE request from JMeter, but getting syntax error (Error 400 Bad request), 
Request url: https://somewebsite.org/Acctid/123?AcctId=123
"AcctId=123" is in Query Parameter.

We have no specific headers except for the Cookie and Accept. No content-encoding.

The same request works perfectly fine from Postman.

Any suggestions what could be wrong with our request?

Best!

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell you what's wrong without seeing your Postman and JMeter configurations.

If the request works in Postman and doesn't in JMeter you could just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman.
5. That's it, JMeter should generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and you should be able to replay the request.